# Minecraft Ghost Block Mod

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to find the name of a Minecraft mod in which you can download a structure and it will put the structure down in translucent blocks which you can then trace. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Zeroless, this isn't the best site for game/mod recommendations (they're actually off-topic here). You're better off asking somewhere like the [Modded Minecraft](https://www.reddit.com/r/ModdedMinecraft) subreddit.

Answer (score 2):

The mod in question is [Litematica](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/litematica), an offshot of no longer maintained Schematica.